# VueSax Notifications displayed wrongly

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuesax

somehow the notifications I want to use from vuesax@next are displayed wrong... maybe it is my fault or it is because of the alpha status form vuesax? here's the code: (I copied it directly from the documentation...)

```
openNotification (title_, text_) { //obviously I put this in the methods from Vue
  this.$vs.notification({
    title: title_,
    text: text_
  })
}
```

and when I want to execute it:

```
this.openNotification('test', 'This is a test')
```

now, when I execute it, the notification gets displayed, but the font is completely wrong... and since it is triggered via js I don't know how to select it via css. normally the standard font from vuejs should be used?

Comment: You should still be able to inspect the element with your browser's dev tools to find out where the font specification is coming from

Answer (score 1):

As Phil said you should inspect the notification and take a look at the class name. Once you have it you would probably try a `font-family: inherit` on that class to see if it takes your font.